# How to concatenate dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have weather data about Min and Max temperatures and Precipitation of various weather stations over a period of 1985-2014. I have found the average Min and Max temperatures for each year using GroupBy in Pandas.

```
data1= data
#Replaceing missing values represented by -9999 with 0
df2=data1.replace(to_replace=-9999,value=0)
#performing groupby over the year part of the string given in Date
df3=data1.groupby(df2.Date.str[0:4])
tmp=df3['MaxTemp'].mean().to_frame()
```

> ```
> Date  MaxTemp
> 1985  153.347945
> 1986  126.963370
> ....    ......
> ```

```
fileName=filePath.split('\\')[-1]
#filename is USC00110072.txt

fname=pd.DataFrame([fileName]*len(tmp.index))
fname.columns=['File']
# mtemp=pd.concat([])
fname.index=[i for i in range(1985,2015)]
fname
```

Now I want to concatenate **tmp** and **fname** dataframes to give me data as such:

> `FileName           Year     MaxTemp
>   USC00110072.txt   1985   153.347945205
>   USC00110072.txt   1986   126.963369963
>   ....              ...     ......`

To do this I used `pandas.concat([fname,tmp], axis=1)` but I am getting following output:

```
              File      MaxTemp
1985    USC00110072.txt   NaN
1986    USC00110072.txt   NaN
1987    USC00110072.txt   NaN
....     ........         ...
1985       NaN          153.347945
1986       NaN          126.963370
1987       NaN          177.602740
```

Please suggest what changes should I make in the **concat** function so that I get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in first dataframes years are strings, in second integers.

So need convert `string`s to `integer`s by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
tmp = (data.replace(to_replace=-9999,value=0)
           .groupby(data.Date.str[0:4].astype(int))
           .mean()
           .to_frame())
```

Also solution should be simplify by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for append new column with same values:

```
df = (data.replace(to_replace=-9999,value=0)
          .groupby(data.Date.str[0:4].astype(int))
          .mean()
          .to_frame()
          .assign(File = fileName))
```